# CGPoint to NSValue and reverse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have code:

```
NSMutableArray *vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Getting mouse coordinates
loc = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
[vertices addObject:loc]; // Adding coordinates to NSMutableArray

//Converting from NSMutableArray to GLfloat to work with OpenGL
int count = [vertices count] * 2; // * 2 for the two coordinates of a loc object
GLFloat []glVertices = (GLFloat *)malloc(count * sizeof(GLFloat));
int currIndex = 0;
for (YourLocObject *loc in vertices) {
    glVertices[currIndex++] = loc.x;
    glVertices[currIndex++] = loc.y;        
}
```

`loc` is CGPoint, so i need somehow to change from CGPoint to NSValue to add it to NSMutableArray and after that convert it back to CGPoint. How could it be done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The class [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has methods `+[valueWithPoint:]` and `-[CGPointValue]`? Is this what you are looking for?

```
//Getting mouse coordinates
NSMutableArray *vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CGPoint location = [self convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:self];
NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:location];
[vertices addObject:locationValue];

//Converting from NSMutableArray to GLFloat to work with OpenGL
NSUInteger count = vertices.count * 2; // * 2 for the two coordinates
GLFloat GLVertices[] = (GLFloat *)malloc(count * sizeof(GLFloat));
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSValue *locationValue = [vertices objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint location = locationValue.CGPointValue;
    GLVertices[i] = location.x;
    GLVertices[i] = location.y;
}
```

Comment: I tried `NSValue *cgpointObj = [NSValue valueWithPoint:loc];`. But how to convert back to CGPoint?

Comment: Something like `CGPoint loc = cgpointObj.pointValue` should work. I added updated code.

Comment: I think its not adding any values. If I write code:|
`NSUInteger sum = vertices.count;
    NSLog(@"count: %lu", sum);`

It always writes that sum = 0. Why? No values have been added? Then why haven't they been added?

Comment: You would better to run Debugger, trace all code and look into variables.

Comment: To convert an NSValue back to a CGPoint this worked for me: `CGPoint tempPoint = tempValue.CGPointValue;`

Comment: @crgt: That's on iOS. `pointValue` is the correct method on the Mac.