# Convert NSValue back to CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cgpoint, nsvalue

I made an `NSMutableArray` like this storing a bunch of `CGPoint`s

```
    safeZonePoints = [NSMutableArray array];
    [safeZonePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(234, 160)]];
    [safeZonePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(284, 210)]];
    [safeZonePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(334, 160)]];
    [safeZonePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(284, 10)]];
    [safeZonePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(234, 160)]];
```

Now I can get the `NSValue`s from the array, but how do I convert an `NSValue` back to `CGPoint`?

Comment: There are docs. If you lookup `valueWithCGPoint` the description provides the inverse operation with "See Also
`– CGPointValue:`".

Comment: Can I still get credit for a chosen answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
NSValue *cgpointObj = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(234, 160)];
CGPoint loc = cgpointObj.pointValue;
```

Check out the following link: [CGPoint to NSValue and reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327249/cgpoint-to-nsvalue-and-reverse)

It should be enough to answer your question.

Comment: I have one more question, is it computationally better to use CGPoint[] over NSMutableArray, and if it is how much better is it.

Comment: Not sure, google it or ask a new question.

Comment: This doesn't work in XCode 10.

Comment: @Jubei this is from over 5 years ago

Comment: @Wyetro I’m just adding knowledge to this post. Is this a reason for you to downvote me? I have improved the post in case somebody stumbles upon this today (like I did).

Comment: @Jubei you can't downvote comments... My point was only that this is from a long time ago. Additionally, the link I have there has the solution: `CGPoint location = locationValue.CGPointValue`